# Scraping HTML forms with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a form like this:

```
<form id="search" method="get" action="search.php">
      <input type="text" name="query" value="Search"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And i want the values in this oder:
method
action
names

```
["get", "search.php", ["query"]]
```

I don't know how to do it in regex. Because this is also multilined string.
I am also very new to regex.

Comment: You wouldn't do it with regex. Why would you want to do it with regex? [Just don't do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: According to me best way to go with any `xml` parsing module

Comment: I would have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1319998 before trying to parse HTML with regex :-)

Answer (score 3):

As a proper way for parsing a HTML or XML document you should use a html(or xml) parser like `beautifulsoup` or `lxml` or ... . but if you just want to use `regex` that not be recommended you can use `re.findall`  as following :

```
>>> [i for j in re.findall(r'method="([^ >"]*)"|action="([^ >"]*)"|name="([^ >"]*)"',s) for i in j if i]
['get', 'search.php', 'query']
```

`[^ >]*` match a string that not contain `space` and `>`.

Comment: You should remove the double quotes from your character classes to avoid a lot of backtraking and possible false results.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes but  then it doesn't be the OP's expected result!

Comment: I removed the double quotes in the pattern. And stripped/removed the double quotes after the matching.

Comment: @Emyen yep it will be a better idea!

Comment: No, you didn't understand : `method="([^ >"]*)"` is what I mean.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ahan, yes, sorry! thanks for reminding and teaching i didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with [Michal Charemza's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319998/michal-charemza) comment to go ahead and read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1319998).

I will give an example using [Lxml](http://lxml.de/). It's a very powerful tool to parse and analyze HTML.

```
import lxml
from lxml.html import fromstring

html = fromstring("""<form id="search" method="get" action="search.php">
                     <input type="text" name="query" value="Search"/>
                     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                     </form> """)
form = html.forms[0] # selecting the first form in the HTML page

# Extracting the data out of the form
print form.action, form.method, form.inputs.keys()
```

Enjoy,

Abdul

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup library.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '''<form id="search" method="get" action="search.php">
      <input type="text" name="query" value="Search"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> k = []
>>> for i in soup.find_all('form'):
        k.append(i['method'])
        k.append(i['action'])
        k.append([j['name'] for j in i.find_all('input', attrs={'name':True})])

    
>>> k
['get', 'search.php', ['query']]
```

Comment: Why even use `re` here? Just add the name argument to the list as you already are, no need to regex out the name from the element converted to a string...